# How to tell wpf that TAB is pressed?

Tags: wpf

I have wpf application in which I am using "ENTER" key as "TAB & Enter". If data are valid then move to next control.

My problem is that I want to raise TAB event programmatically. Please provide some code.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to send a TAB key event to the application. Instead, use the [`MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.movefocus.aspx) method to move focus to the next control